# Roger Ascham his language

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, early-modern-english

As I was finishing Ascham's "Toxophilus" I've stumbled over this phrase, the meaning of which remained unclear to me:  "An other wil stand poyntinge his shafte at the marke a good whyle and by and by he wyll gyue hym a whip, and awaye or a man wite". The context can be seen [here](http://www.archerylibrary.com/books/toxophilus/second_book06.html).

I came to understand the phrase thus: "Another will stand pointing his arrow at the target for a good while and on and on he will give himself a whip (on the arm?) and go away before anyone should know".

I'm not sure, however. Firstly, what does the pronoun "him" refer to? Does it denote an archer? Ascham uses "himself" quite regularly in similar cases, e.g. "defend his country, and save himself from his enemy", "archer ought to provide for himself" etc. Why not here? "Him" could possibly be applied to the shaft, although I have trouble imagining how one would go about flogging an arrow. At first I thought maybe by a "whip" Ascham meant an act of loosing an arrow, but "whip" must mean "a blow or stroke with, or as with, a whip", since Oxford English Dictionary uses this particular sentence to illustrate the meaning. Even though I have some thoughts as to how standing with an arrow drawn can result in an injury, still it feels like a conjecture.

"By and by" could alternatively mean "consequently", or "soon" even, so it doesn't really clear things up.

Finally, I'm at a loss regarding why Ascham would put "wit" in a subjunctive mood. Does it add any peculiar meaning to the sentence? Does the archer in question try to leave before anybody takes notice of his awkward shooting? Or is it just a phrase meaning "very shortly"? Why then not say "or a man wot" instead?

So, am I the only nitwit who's confused by Ascham's usage of English or is it a genuinely complicated phrase allowing for interpretation? I'm eager to know.

P.S. As a bonus question, what's the meaning of the preposition "of" in a phrase: "All the discommodities ... [can not be] soon reckoned of me, they be so many." Same source. I couldn't find a similar usage of the word anywhere.

Comment: Could you give a link to the text and mention where the specific paragraph is please. This makes it easier for us to read the prior text. Thanks. Note that the use of 'him' can be reflexive and occur where today we would say 'himself'.  Example: "*Then I got me a piece of the goat's flesh and broiled it on the coals*" https://goo.gl/m3p2jn   Nowadays we would say "I got *myself* a piece of the goat's flesh..." or simply "I got a piece of the goat's flesh..."

Comment: The Internet-page with the corresponding portion of Ascham's text is already linked at the end of my question's first paragraph, but here: [http://www.archerylibrary.com/books/toxophilus/second_book06.html](http://www.archerylibrary.com/books/toxophilus/second_book06.html) Also, in regards to "him", I absolutely agree that it can be a substitute for "himself", but Ascham's specific usage of these two words seems to indicate otherwise (see my initial question's 3rd paragraph).

Comment: Regarding your P.S., **reckoned of**:  *of* with the past participle in passive constructions expresses agency.  It can be paraphrased "by".  They cannot be reckoned by me.  See **of** in the MED, #22.

Comment: Why **wite**?  "or a man wite" means "ere a man know" and thus expresses an irrealis condition.

Comment: @TimRomano, thanks for the answer and a reference to MED. It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 4):

*whip* might be used either in reference to the shaft/bow or (as pointed out by chasly in the comment) to his person, and this in the sense of *jolt*, *a sudden movement*. (The usage of *whip* in the sense of "move fast or suddenly" can be traced back to the 18th century (at least, didn't have time for searching further), as in "whipping up the stairs".)
*away*, meanwhile, may allude to the shaft being loosened:

"Another will stand pointing his arrow at the target for a good while and after some time *he'll make a sudden movement and the arrow is gone* before anyone should know".

**or**

"Another will stand pointing his arrow at the target for a good while and after some time *he'll suddenly loosen the arrow, and it is gone* before anyone should know".

This is, of course, interpretative guesswork for now, and might be completely off the mark (no pun).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. A couple of things though.

Comment: "_and this in the sense of jolt, a sudden movement_" As I've mentioned before, the very phrase in question makes an appearance in OED as an example for a specific meaning of the word "whip", namely "a blow or stroke with, or as with, a whip". Your suggestion, while perfectly legitimate, seems to contradict this. Then, "_away, meanwhile, may allude to the shaft being loosened_" Can it though? I figured it was used elliptically, meaning "go away", since the primary actor of this sentence is the archer. Could you maybe recall an example of the usage, that you suggested? Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of *loosened* and *loosen* (made less tight), did you mean *loosed* and *loose* (let fly)? Guns are fired; arrows are loosed.

Comment: +1 This matches perfectly with the OED's definition 10a: " A sudden, brisk, or hasty movement; a start;"

Comment: +1. **Him** is referring to the **shafte**.

Comment: My bad, Grenelef, when answering I somehow failed to remember you'd already gone through that! Also: you may be a nitwit, I wouldn't know, but certainly not for asking those questions, which are rather interesting. Also: it's a great book. Also: I'll try to help find an answer to your other question as soon as I find some time.

Comment: I would assume, since the meaning "A sudden, brisk, or hasty movement; a start;" fits this sentence so well, and is the right time period (Ascham predates the OED's first citation for this sense by 11 years) that the OED somehow managed to get this one wrong.

Comment: So, the general consensus seems to be that a certain example for OED's definition 3a of "whip" is incorrect. Okay, that is interesting. And I've got to admit, that the definition 10a with a shaft as an object provides for a clearer sense here. However, it raises an issue with "awaye", because, as OED states, "elliptical uses [of "away"] with a verb suppressed [are] simulating an imperative or (rarely) infinitive.

Comment: I think "awaye" there is rather dramatic, like "whoosh".

Comment: @TimRomano, one more thing, if I may... Am I correct in assuming that the phrase "a man with a staff to make room in a game place" a bit down the line refers to [Prize Playing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prize_Playing)? What do you think? (And it is a "staff" in the book, not a "shaft" as in the online copy.)

Comment: Alternatively, it could refer to a person, who uses a stick to make his way through the croud at some sort of a show.

Comment: @Grenelef: *And an other swynges hys bowe aboute hym, as it were a man with a staffe to make roume in a game place.*   You could be right about that. At this point in the text, Ascham is describing all of the farcical things archers do as the arrow flies, in order to correct its trajectory--stamping, leaping, shouting cursing at the arrow, twisting the body, holding the foot in the air, etc -- as if those actions could have some effect on the arrow's flight. Maybe it's an allusion to the staff-swinging Hodge in *Gammer Gurton's Needle*, a popular Tudor farce.

Comment: @TimRomano, thanks for the suggestion. Still, according to Wikipedia, the earliest probable production date of Gammer Gurton's Needle is around 1553, whereas Toxophilus was first published in 1545. I'm not sure if "in a game place" means specifically "in the arena/on stage" or could also mean "at a performance/among the viewers".

Comment: @Grenelef: I remembered  the consensus opinion on the dating being no more precise than "not long after the dissolution of the monasteries" under Henry VIII.  But I'm no scholar of Tudor drama.